# ListView of HorizontalListView

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontallist

I am working on an Android application and needs to add HorizontalListView inside ListView. So, the case is, HorizontalListView contains only the images (dynamic) and ListView can contain multiple rows of HorizontalListView. I have succeeded in creating the HorizontalListView but stuck on the part where I need to add dynamic HorizontalListView in the ListView. I tried to google around but couldn't find any help. So, is there any idea or suggestion to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look on [this](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) and [this](https://github.com/lalit3686/VerticalHorizontalListView). I have used the first one and its working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using AndroidStudio and unable to configure any of the project. I am new to AS, so any help?

Comment: What difficulty you are facing during the import?

Comment: When I import the VerticalListView, it imports successfully but doesn't run (As you know AS creates gradle build) so while running it throws dexed libs kind of exception